# How to remove default div wrappers from fields output via custom field formatter?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a custom field and custom field formatter created in Drupal 8. I need to remove the default FIELD VALUE wrappers so that I can build an HTML table with the field values.

The field formatter is currently using a custom twig template, but I `<div>`'s are being rendered prior to the template, so I can't remove them there.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div wrapper you are looking for is probably in `field.html.twig`. Drupal provides a theme name suggestion for a custom field type automatically, so you can override this template by placing `field--myfieldtype.html.twig` in the theme templates folder.

If you want you can deliver a default template with the custom field module, like the comment module does for the comment field:

```
core/modules/comment/templates/field--comment.html.twig
```

Then you need to define a theme hook in *mymodule.module*.

Example from the comment module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function comment_theme() {
  return [
    // ...
    'field__comment' => [
      'base hook' => 'field',
    ],
  ];
}
```